# Not able to set javascript variable back to null after defining it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the variable `selectedColumnIndex` back to null after using it each time.

I need to be able to check that a new `selectedColumnIndex` value has been set after each use. It could be used once or dozens of times in a row (it's for "cut and insert" functionality in a table-style UI component).

If I put a browser breakpoint at the variable `var check`, `selectedColumnIndex` will show as `null`. But then if `$(document).on('click', '.columnUpdatesInsert', function () { }` runs again *without* `$(document).on('click', '.columnUpdates', function () { }` ever running, `selectedColumnIndex` will be back to the previous value.

```
var selectedColumnIndex = null;
$(document).on('click', '.columnUpdates', function () {
    selectedColumnIndex = $(this).attr("data-columnindex");
});

$(document).on('click', '.columnUpdatesInsert', function () {
    if (selectedColumnIndex != null) {
        // get variables from click element etc.

        $(updateColumnPosition(tableId, selectedColumnIndex, newColumnIndex));
    }
    else {
        alert("No column was selected to move.");
    }
});

function updateColumnPosition(tableId, selectedColumnIndex, newColumnIndex) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Task/UpdateColumnIndex",
        data: { projectId: _projectId, tableId: tableId, selectedColumnIndex: selectedColumnIndex, newColumnIndex: newColumnIndex },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                // do other unrelated work

                selectedColumnIndex = null; // this successfully sets it to null, but it is getting set back to the previous value before this code is explicitly setting it again. 
                var check = 0;
            }
            else {
                // handle error
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: assigning a value of the argument `selectedColumnIndex` does not change the global `var` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you are passing selectedColumnIndex as an arg to the function it becomes a local to that function.

Try not passing the value selectedColumnIndex as arg and use it as global all the time.

```
var selectedColumnIndex = null;
$(document).on('click', '.columnUpdates', function () {
    selectedColumnIndex = $(this).attr("data-columnindex");
});

$(document).on('click', '.columnUpdatesInsert', function () {
    if (selectedColumnIndex != null) {
        // get variables from click element etc.

        $(updateColumnPosition(tableId, newColumnIndex));
    }
    else {
        alert("No column was selected to move.");
    }
});

function updateColumnPosition(tableId, newColumnIndex) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Task/UpdateColumnIndex",
        data: { projectId: _projectId, tableId: tableId, selectedColumnIndex: selectedColumnIndex, newColumnIndex: newColumnIndex },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                // do other unrelated work

                selectedColumnIndex = null; // this successfully sets it to null, but it is getting set back to the previous value before this code is explicitly setting it again. 
                var check = 0;
            }
            else {
                // handle error
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        },
    });
}
```